# Log4j Common class project

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I need some help with `log4j` and my application. I have on JAR with 3 packages listed as below.

Class A and class B have a main class so I can start two different instances of the application at the same time, one from class A and the other from class B.

what I want to have is my application running from class A have to log to `appender1`
and my application running from class B have to log to `appender2`

The problem is that the logs from class C are writing either in class A appender and Class B appender : when I run class A I have

appender1:

Start A
Doing something
End A

appender 2:

Doing something

I don't want to write to appender2 when running class A just to appender1. 
Same thing with class B I don't want to write to appender1 only in appender2

Thanks for your advices.

here is a schema of my classes and log4j:

My JAR:

- com.myAppl.package1.A
- com.myAppl.package2.B
- com.myAppl.package3.C

-

```
Class A {
    LOG = LogFactory.getLog(A.class);

    main() {
        LOG.info("Start A");
        new C().doSomething();
        LOG.info("End A");
    }

}

Class B {
    LOG = LogFactory.getLog(B.class);

    main() {
        LOG.info("Start B");
        new C().doSomethingElse();
        LOG.info("End B");
    }

}

Class C {
    LOG = LogFactory.getLog(C.class);

    doSomething() {*
        LOG.info("Doing something");
    }

    doSomethingElse() {
        LOG.info("Doing something else");
    }

}
```

LOG4J.xml

```
...

<logger name="com.myAppl.package1" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="appender1"/>
</logger>

<logger name="com.myAppl.package2" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="appender2"/>
</logger>

<logger name="com.myAppl.package3" additivity="false">
    <level value="info" />
    <appender-ref ref="appender1"/>
    <appender-ref ref="appender2"/>
</logger>
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which version of log4j you are using. With version 2 you can attach Filters to appenders. http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html

I'd hope you can set some [ThreadContext](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/thread-context.html) or something and filter on that